# How to get the enum value with same name as key?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have enums as following:

```
private static enum CD1 { CC, COR, PO };
private static enum CD2 { OMA, PBO, VAR };
private static enum CD3  { USD, EUR, GBP };
private static enum CD4  { IR, CD, COT };
```

When I say CD1.CC, I want CC, not 0;

I don't want to put a constructor in every enum and override toString to return value;

```
private static enum CD1 { 
 CC("CC"), COR("COR"), PO("PO") ; 
 private String val;

 CD1(String val); this.val = val;

 public String toString() {
  return val;
 }
```

Is there a way to genericize this, so that I don't have to write a constructor for each enum?

EDIT:

Is there a way to avoid using enumVal.name() as well? I am planning to use just enum.enumVal. But, wondering if that is possible. Sorry, wasn't being clear in the question.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two. The short versions of the enums should produce the same thing as the long versions. What is the difference you are seeing? FYI, returning `name()` from `toString()` or just using `name()` would have the same result.

Comment: For what you want, you shouldn't be overriding the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString()) method. The docs says - *Returns the name of this enum constant...*.

Comment: @BheshGurung Yes, I don't have to override toString(). It is my oversight and a bad question perhaps. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with " I am planning to use just enum.enumVal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
enumVal.name()
```

This is built in to Java enums

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using enumVal.name() as well? I am planning to use just enum.enumVal. But, wondering if that is possible. Sorry, wasn't being clear in the question. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Enum.name()` method or just `println()` it directly.

```
System.out.println(CD1.COR); // prints: COR
```

<s>If you wouldn't like to call `name()` explicitly; just override `toString()`</s>
Just dug into the source code; turns out it's the default behaviour *(as pointed by @Puce)*

```
public final String name() {
    return name;
}

public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

with the difference being that `name()` cannot be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can get the label you have decided to use for the enum constant by using the name() method.

name() is intended to return the label.  This method is intended for use in programs and applications that depend on this representation.

toString() is intended to be overridden or used by programmers to create a more "end user appropriate" display of the information.

It sounds to me like you want to use the name() function.